# chaining of a memberfunction call with constructor

Tags: c++

```cpp
class A {
  public:
    A(void) =default;

    A& foo(void)
    {
      return *this;
    }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  A a =A{}.foo();
  A b{};
  A c{}.foo();

  return 0;
}
```

```
C:\temp\cpp>clang test.cpp
test.cpp:15:8: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
   15 |   A c{}.foo();
      |        ^
      |        ;
1 error generated.
```

Why does the compiler complain about `A c{}.foo()`?

Is there a way to avoid the assignment?

I know that in `A a =A{}.foo()`, the compiler will optimize away the temporary, but maybe `A` has no public copy ctor.

Comment: `A c{}.foo();` is wrong. You need `A c{}; c.foo();`

Comment: You can `A c{A{}.foo()};`, but anyway it's code smell to initialize from a reference to temporary, even if it works by the grace of compiler

Comment: `A a =A{}.foo();` is not assignment.

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov That won't work with private copy ctor as OP mentioned.

Comment: What do you want `A c{}.foo();` to achieve that cannot be done with `A c;  c.foo();` ?

Comment: I just asked myself why the compiler does not allow to chain both (constructor and member function call).

Comment: consider that constructors are rather special beasts. They arent functions with a name that return something like other members functions. Chaining is based on functions return value though

Comment: @albert you chained constructor and member function call when defined `a`. What compiler didn't allow, is combining declaration statement and expression statement, which is just not a thing syntactically in C++, it should be either one thing or another. See [C++ statements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements)

Comment: @Alexey,  A c{A{}.foo()}; does not smell, the temporary is valid til the ;

Comment: @albert I believe the temporary is valid in C++11 and above, so I'd call it a smell, I'd rather not overengineer simple things :)

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov I don't think C++11 changed anything here (other than allowing `A{}` in addition to `A()`). And I don't see any code smell here. Initializing from a reference to temporary is very common, e.g. `int x = std::max(10, 20);`.

Comment: In `E.foo()`, `E`  must be an expression whose value is an object. `A{}` is such an expression (but it is not a constructor call - you can't call the constructor yourself). `A c{}` is not an expression at all.

Comment: @AlexeyS.Larionov you must be confusing something. Copy constructors take a reference, so you are basically saying that constructing from a temporary would be a code smell, and that in turn would mean that move constructing is a code smell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of a variable declaration is (roughly speaking) one of:

```
type name = value;
type name(values...);
type name{values...};
```

`A c{}.foo();` fits neither of those.